# tell me where I am or where am I? In this situation

Tags: grammar

So couple of my classmates are chatting in a group & ...

**A:** Turn off your GPS, now everyone knows where you are!

**B:** Ok then tell me where I am/where am I?

Which one is correct in this situation?

My thought was because she already knows where she is, tell me where I am is the correct response here.

Comment: Note that **A** uses _where you are_: Wh-word + subject + auxiliary. That's the correct formula The **B** version with that formula is _Where I am_. Got all that?

Comment: Poorly formulated question with horrible spelling and bad grammar.

Comment: im sorry for bad grammar its my first english semester